# Prevent non-fixed elements from scrolling when reaching the end of a fixed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer for it.

Basically, I have a fixed positioned sidebar that contains a menu and the rest of the page.

When scrolling the fixed sidebar and reaching the end, the rest of the page starts to scroll to. I know this is "normal behaviour" but i need to prevent this from happening.

I also tried to position the rest of the page (container) as `fixed` and using `overflow:auto` on it and that does the job but it interferes with the `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true` property in my asp.net application.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix would be to disable scrolling on the container as long as you hover over the menu, and restore it when you hover something else:

```
$('.menu').hover(function() {
    $('.container').css('overflow', 'hidden'); 
}, function() {
    $('.container').css('overflow', 'auto');
});
```

Or if the menu precedes the container in the HTML you could even try:

```
.menu:hover + .container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

As commented below, this is what fixed the problem without a flickering scroll bar:

jQuery:

```
$('.menu').hover(function() { 
    $('body').addClass("noscroll"); 
}, function() { 
    $('body').removeClass("noscroll"); 
});
```

CSS:

```
body.noscroll { 
    position: fixed; 
    overflow-y: scroll; 
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: This helps, but it makes the site flicker as it shows and hides the scrollbar while hovering the menu. What I did was modifying your code like this:
`$('.menu').hover(function() {
    $('body').addClass("noscroll");
}, function() {
    $('body').removeClass("noscroll");
}); `

and on the css side: `body.noscroll
{
    position: fixed; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}`

Comment: ...and set `body{overflow-y:scroll;}` by default, so it doesn-t flickr.